# How to store a security.krb5.EncryptionKey object into a keystore or convert it into a SecretKey object?

Tags: java, security, kerberos, keystore

I am using this guide http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-decrypt-kerberos-gss-ap-req.html to extract the secret key from a Kerberos ticket.

Now I want to store the key I got into a keystore or perhaps another secure equivalent, the problem is that the Key object I get is an security.krb5.EncryptionKey type and the keystore accepts SecretKey objects only.
I am not stuck on how to store the key or convert it to a more common format
If anyone has an idea about this I would appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: I needed to store the key in a keystore for further purposes, but the key store did not accept the key object used in that guide so I needed to convert it to a more common format

Comment: You did not answer my question. You repeated the same stuff as in the subject. What do you intend with the key?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't get the question the first time. I intend to use it for a key derivation function later on that I am testing but to do that we decided to build a system and use Kerberos as the authentication and key exchange mechanism

Comment: Actually, I would using the internals at all. I should suffice to work with JGSS only and use Kerberos 5 OID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rereading the code a few times I noticed that the key is originally in the SecretKey object format, the author of the blog changes it later to EncryptionKey, I just by passed that and got the information I needed